# Cannot SSH to local network hosts by name

Tags: networking, ssh, 16.04

Recently it seems as if my Ubuntu 16.04 laptop has lost the ability to communicate with other hosts on my network by name. I used to be able to run `ssh pi@bifrost.local` or similar. However, about 3 days ago, I was no longer able to do that. Neither `pi@bifrost` or `pi@bifrost.local` work. I get this error instead: `ssh: Could not resolve hostname bifrost.local: Name or service not known`. I have not changed my hosts file or router config in this time.

EDIT: Name resolving works fine on my 14.04 laptop and my Pies.

Comment: Your question does not say whether you looked at your host file or not, is the info for that server still in your host file?

Comment: I didn't need to add entries for the hosts before. Host name discovery should just work out of the box. My other machines have no problem and their `hosts` files just contain the standard lines defining `localhost` and hostname.

Comment: Your dns server is still set to your router, and not public DNS?

Comment: Do you know what DNS name servers they are pointing to?  As you probably know names are either set statically(hosts), or via DNS, so it would seem to me that something changed.

Comment: I did ifconfig to find out my ethernet iface, mine is enp0s25, I then put in this command to see my DNS servers:  nmcli dev show enp0s25 | grep IP4 this showed me the servers, try doing this just change enp0s25 to your ethernet iface.

Comment: I forgot, try it on the working machine, and the non working, and see if they are different.

Comment: What does `avahi-resolve -n bifrost.local` say? What is in the `hosts` line of your /etc/nsswitch.conf file?

Comment: Ah, I see what happened. For some reason, I'm missing the avahi-resolve package on this machine...